# Props not getting passed to onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a onClick that uploads data, I need to pass props to that onclick function from the render its in.

```
onClick={this.handleEditsUpload}
```

to

```
handleEditsUpload() {
  const { selected } = this.props;
}
```

`selected` is showing as `selected: []` in `handleEditsUpload()`.

I have tried passing the props by doing:

```
onClick={this.handleEditsUpload(...this.props)}
```

which I thought would work as I am doing this elsewhere.

Not sure where to go from here, any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

You no need to specifically pass props to handleEditsUpload event handler function

Change

```
  onClick={this.handleEditsUpload(...this.props)}
```

To

```
 onClick={this.handleEditsUpload}
```

Because this.props are available directly inside handleEditsUpload.

What you need to make sure is that whether you did binding for handleEditsUpload in constructor. if not then add below line in constructor

```
      this.handleEditsUpload = this.handleEditsUpload.bind(this);
```

So now you will have access to props inside handleEditsUpload function

```
    handleEditsUpload(){
         const { selected } = this.props;
    }
```

There is no need for passing props to handler function hence I don’t recommend doing that. If you still want to do in that approach then call the function in arrow way because you need to pass params

```
   onClick={() => this.handleEditsUpload(...this.props)}
```

Comment: You can also define `handleEditsUpload` as an arrow function: `handleEditsUpload = () => { const { selected } = this.props; }` and skip the whole constructor `bind(this)` part. Because of how arrow function work its `this` will be `handleEditsUpload`'s defining scope (the component) instead of its caller. It saves a lot of repetitive effort in components with many functions.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending onClick a function's *result* instead of its reference.
What happen during `onClick={this.handleEditsUpload(...this.props)}` is that handleEditsUpdload is called with the provided props, then its return value (null in this case) is assigned to onClick.

If you want to call handleEditsUpload when the button is clicked, give it a function reference instead:

```
onClick={() => this.handleEditsUpload(...this.props)}
```

The difference is that this time you're assigning the arrow function `() => this.handleEditsUpload(...this.props)` to onClick, instead of a return value.